# Force error message to Zend Form Element

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

```
    // Process the forms
    if (($this->getRequest()->isPost())
            && ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())) {

        // Initiate response
        $status = false;
        $msg = '';
        $zf = null;

        // Error test
        $form->getElement('no')->addError('This is the error message');            

        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

        // Everything is good
            $status = true;

        } else {

        // Get the error messages
            $zf = $form->getMessages();
        }

        // Setup the response
        $result = json_encode(array('status' => $status,
                                    'msg' => $msg,
                                    'zf' => $zf));

        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($result);

        return;

    } else {
        // Populate the form
    }
```

As you can see, I've used `$form->getElement('no')->addError('This is the error message');` to force error on the form element, but `$form->getMessages();` would still return `NULL`. So, what should I do to force error on the selected form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a bug report for this issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11088. I'll update this question if there's any new progress.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the get the ErrorMessages()

```
$form->getErrorMessages()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, I got nothing from `$form->getErrorMessages()`. I tried outputting it into Frirebug and I got empty array.